# Spring boot + JPA - SharedEntityManagerCreator opens sessions at startup

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Given the following setup :

- Spring boot 1.4
- Hibernate 5 / Multi-Tenancy is ON / MultiTenancyStrategy is DataBase.
- `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`, `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none`, `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false`, `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

When enabling tracing, I have noticed that hibernate opens `n` sessions at startup.

The `n` number is **oddly** equal to the number of methods annotated by `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(readOnly=true)`.

I also noticed that the component responsible of opening those sessions is the `org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator`, and precisely the following part of code :

```java
@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    //...

    boolean isNewEm = false;
    if (target == null) {
        logger.debug("Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation");
        target = (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.properties) ?
                this.targetFactory.createEntityManager(this.properties) :
                this.targetFactory.createEntityManager());
        isNewEm = true;
    }

    //...
}
```

And here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmESy.png) to a screenshot showing the method being proxied.

**That being said, my question is :**

Is there any explanation for this behavior because I'm expecting that no session will be opened until the application has completely started or a data manipulation operation *(loading schema)* is required during startup (which is not my case)...

Comment: Spring Boot JPA starter's transitives pull in tomcat jdbc which I believe does connection pooling, using tomcat dbcp IIRC.

Comment: This code is from an Invocation handler, so you would need to know which method is being proxied. Maybe you could set a breakpoint and make a screenshot af the callstack.